# Create aws redshift user with access to given schema including drop tables

Tags: amazon-redshift

I would like to seperate access to two existing data schemas (with tables already created) in redshift by creating two new users and granting them access to their relevant schemas.

So `user_1` should have access only to `schema_1` and `user_2` should have access only to `schema_2`.

By access I mean that the users should be able to `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP` from all current tables (no matter who created them) and to `CREATE` new tables on their schemas.

I have found the below statements to create a new user and to give them specific access types:

Create new user:

```
 CREATE USER user_1 WITH PASSWORD 'password_1';
```

Grant usage to the given schema:

```
 GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "schema_1" TO user_1;
```

Assign privileges:

```
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "schema_1" TO user_1;
```

Alter Default Privileges to maintain the permissions on new tables

```
 ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "schema_1" GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO user_1;
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) it shows how to add all privileges required except for `DROP` tables. When testing this it errors with `ERROR: must be owner of relation table_to_drop`.

I alternatively have tried to grant all privileges as below...

```
 GRANT ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "schema_1" TO user_1;
```

...but this doesn't overwrite the requirement of it needing to be the owner of the table that drops is able to drop it.

So question is is it possible to restrict a user to a given schema with acccess to it as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Only the owner of the table, the schema owner, or a superuser can drop a table.  So user_1 should be the owner of schema_1 and user_2 should be the owner of schema_2 if you want them to be able to drop tables in their respective schema.

I am assuming that user_1 and user_2 are not superusers or the question is moot.